# Areas in self-hosted (OWIN) Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm setting up a new web application. We have services that perform continous background operations (CQRS projections), which is why we host them in windows services. We'd like to use these services to host the corresponding web APIs as well (otherwise we couldn't serve in-memory projections).

In addition, we'd like to have SignalR support to inform the clients whenever a projection was updated. We have a separate ASP.NET MVC application because we use Razor views for templating.

We'd like to split the web API into several areas - similar to how it's possible to do in an ASP.NET (MVC) application - with one area per bounded context. Such as `http://localhost:8080/Orders/api/{Controller}/{id}` or `http://localhost:8080/Foo/api/{Controller}/{id}`

*At a later point we'd also like to have the controllers, projections, models etc. in separate assemblies. Again, one per context*

Is it possible to define areas in a self-hosted Web API project? Would it perhaps be possible to route them to controllers from specific assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the article in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/ I've solved it.

I have to implement my own `IHttpControllerSelector` and replace the default one in `Startup.cs` like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// OWIN startup class
/// </summary>
public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Owin configuration
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">App builder</param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // We might have to resolve the referenced assemblies here or else we won't find them. This is a quick and dirty way to make sure that the assembly containing the controller has been loaded

        var x = typeof(CarRental.Reservations.Application.Read.Web.FooController);

        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{boundedcontext}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Enable routing via bounded context
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new BoundedContextControllerSelector(config)); 

        app.UseWebApi(config);

        // Configure SignalR
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

With `BoundedContextControllerSelector` being an implementation of `IHttpControllerSelector` very close to the code in the example: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/dd207952fa86#Samples/WebApi/NamespaceControllerSelector/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

I use the namespace to determine the bounded context and now have a clear separation of web api endpoints for each context :)